# Parsley error message on hidden field

Tags: parsley.js

I need to validate a single selection row on a datatables. I don't know which is the best way it can be done. Right now I've put a hidden type input that is filled by javascript when the users clicks a row on datatables. When I validate form, parsley doesn't submit it if required hidden input is blank, but no error message is shown.

I've also tried to get field:error event, but it is not fired on hidden field.

```
window.Parsley.on('field:error', function() {
// This global callback will be called for any field that fails validation.
console.log('Validation failed for: ', this.$element);
});
```

Is there any way I can show with parsley a validation error message if hidden field is blank on form submit? I know I can do it without parsley, just checking if field is blank on submit, but as the other form fields are being validated through parsley I would like to know a way to show parsley error message somewhere in the form by parsley.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have removed the "type=hidden" part of the `excluded` option, it should work fine.

Tip: You should trigger an 'input' event on your hidden field whenever you modify it.

Post a working example if it still doesn't work.